# Trigger angular js autocomplete when setting the value of input field with java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-material

I am using javascript to update the value of an input field of a website.

However, after updating the value of the input field, I cannot trigger the autocomplete.

The triggering of the autocomplete works when I manually type into the input field but my javascript code does not trigger it.

I have tried .focus .blur and keyboard events with no luck.

I am currently trying to solve this riddle using CJS extension for chrome which allows me to inject javascript to the input field on the AngularJS website.

When I click the input field, it sets the value and then unsuccessfully triggers the autocomplete.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

My code:

```
var focusedInput = null;

$('input').click(function(){
        focusedInput = $(this);
        focusedInput.focus();
        simulateKeysPressed("North");
        alert("Ohh Hey");
    })

function simulateKeysPressed( sData)
{
    focusedInput.val(sData);
    focusedInput.blur();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried triggering a `change` event manually? That should launch all listeners that are binded to the `onchange` event

```
function simulateKeysPressed( sData)
{
    focusedInput.val(sData).trigger("change");
    focusedInput.blur();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback. I have just appended your solution and unfortunately no luck with the .trigger("change").

Comment: You could try with some other events, such as `.trigger("input")`,  `.trigger("keyup")` or `.trigger("keydown")` and see if some of them work.